# Whats the point of the feedhorn on a dish antenna, why cant the dish just have a matching network attached to the dish directly?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, wireless, impedance-matching, faraday-cage

Apologies if any thing i have said is incorrect. But, in the context of antennas, an unmatched feedpoint often leads to reflections, impacting both transmission and reception. It appears that if the feedpoint isn't properly matched, waves might not propagate and could be reflected, akin to the behavior seen in Faraday cages or dish antennas (which is what is desired in this case).

Given this understanding, I'm curious about the possibility of incorporating a matching network directly at the feedpoint of a dish antenna instead of using it solely to reflect waves towards the feedhorn at the center.Is this not done due to optimizing transmitted power or effective radiated power rather than its actually ability to work?

Comment: Comparing your title with the body of your question, they appear to be asking different things.

Comment: @Andyaka my bad, ive added “to the dish itself “ at the end. Is that better?

Comment: What now confuses me is that you can't replace a feedhorn because it gathers the focused EM waves when receiving and, sprays out the transmitted signals when transmitting whereas a matching network does neither.

Comment: Have you (OP) looked at any ray diagrams showing how a reflector antenna works?

Comment: @Andyaka I see, but I specifically mean that if the dish was matched and signals could propagate from the dish directly, why is this worse than focusing the em waves to the feedhorn like you just mentioned.

Comment: @SteveSh no, I probably should. But i am more curious as to why the dish itself cant be used as the antenna like a patch antenna as apposed to needing to concentrate the waves to a feedhorn and have the coax from that

Comment: @Georgekirby honestly, to understand the ray diagrams are like two steps before you understand antennas well enough to answer that question. You gotta learn the basics here, no shortcut.

Comment: @MarcusMüller is there any goto book you recommend? Or just general research into a rabbit hole type thing?

Comment: Just research what a parabolic reflector does.

Comment: As I understand iit, the feed horn IS the antenna - the dish is just a reflector that directs the signal emitted by the feed horn in the desired direction. (or, on receive, directs signals received from the desired direction to the feed horn).

Comment: Yes.  That's it in a nutshell.

Answer (score 2):

An antenna is but the matching network between the wave in the waveguide (whether that waveguide is a microstrip line on a PCB, a coax cable or rectangular waveguide "piping") to free-space impedance.

Especially in the rect horn you see that quite nicely: The cross-section geometry of a rectangular waveguide defines its impedace for waves of a certain frequency. If you want these waves to continue propagating in the same direction, but move from the waveguide impedance to freespace impedance, you'll have to gradually change the cross-section!

Of course, the actual shape of an antenna does not only define its impedance-matching behaviour, it also defines its directivity. Even if cutting off the end of whatever you use to match your impedances with (and in the ranges you typically operate satellite dishes at, chances are, that's also a gradually changing waveguide construction), it would radiate in a wide range of angles – you don't want that, you want your feed to illuminate exactly the dish.

Comment: Thankyou, I probably worded my question pretty badly but you gave me alot of insight. So would it be correct that your saying, you could have say a coax connected directly to the metal part of the dish (and match the dish too), but this has disadvantages as appose to reflecting this onto the feedhorn, such as directivity?

Comment: no, that's not at all what I said. It's wrong!

Comment: Then im a little confused, i got from your comment that the geometry of the dish alters the directivity and impedance, so why couldn’t this be used directly as an antenna?

Comment: no, that's simply not what I said! I was speaking about the feed horn, not the dish.

Comment: Ohhh i see , so the feedhorn is the waveguide in this sense - my apologies. But i still wonder about my original question, why can you just use the dish part itself as the antenna like a patch antenna, is it worse than using the feedhorn (using the dish to reflect the waves instead)?

Comment: no, the waveguide is where the signal for the feedhorn comes from

Comment: the dish itself simply isn't an antenna, you can't use it as such. I mean, you can use the same metal, add a feedpoint somewhere, and get a terribly mismatching aperture antenna with absurd antenna pattern, but it really makes no sense at all.

Comment: Oh i see, i havent really covered waveguides yet. And is there a specific reason for that? Is it just not a good shape? I was under the impression most metallic stuff could be matched to stop reflections, i get some shapes actually emmit better than others - is it just a bad shape or something?

Comment: @Georgekirby honestly, this is getting absurd. You're basically trying to skip 1 or 2 years of education in electromagnetics, waves, transmission line theory and antennas here– that won't work. Your question "is it just a bad shape or something" means we would really need to write you a book on the whole theory of antennas.

Comment: My degree isnt in electrical engineering, its hard for me to cover it and my degree at the same time but it rly interests me, im not on-purposely trying skip the knowledge, i just thought it was worth seeing if there was a somewhat (straight forward to a non electrical guy) straight answer. Ironically i have stated reading the book by balanis but I didn’t think it would harm asking here

Comment: The parabolic dish is peculiar in that the matching and wavefront-forming are mostly separated. The feed only has to illuminate the dish without spilling too much around the edges. A well-designed feed is, by itself, a well-matched antenna: it just doesn't have the directivity the dish provides.

Comment: @JohnDoty Thankyou for your help. I understand more now

Answer (score 1):

The parabolic dish is a phase adjusting device: when illuminated by spherical waves from the focus, the reflection has the phase structure of a plane wave. It thus makes a beam. If the illumination comes from a different place, this doesn't work.

There are, of course, many other ways to achieve this. With a suitably chosen pattern of conductors in a dish shape, one could feed it from a point on the surface rather than the focus. However, for that approach, the dish shape has no special virtue: you might as well make it flat.

Comment: Many thanks, so essentially the dish itself could be used directly as the antenna, but it would have different directivity properties, as appose to having the feed point at the feedhorn?

Comment: No.  The dish needs the feed horn to function properly - as desired.  On receive, you need to collect the energy at the focus of the reflector.  On transmit you need to emit the RF at the focus.

Comment: Thanks, so why cant it just be used as a slightly curved patch antenna (the dish part)?

Comment: @Georgekirby It could if you patterned the conductor to get the right phasing. But then, why curve it?

Comment: Idk it was more curiosity that actually use cases. When you say focus point in your question is this referring to where the feedhorn would be? Also, when you said it might as well be straight (the dish if it was directly as an antenna), why isnt that used instead? Thanks

Comment: @Georgekirby this is really answered by looking at a ray diagram of a satellite dish, as pointed out to you in the comments under your question. We can't shovel the images faster into your brain, you do need to do some own work here.

Comment: The focus of a paraboloid is a geometric term. It happens to be where you should put a point source of radiation for the paraboloid to transform the waves into plane waves, assuming the paraboloid is a simple, continuous conductive surface. Other sorts of surfaces have different properties.